# How do I concatenate the value of a variable into the name of another in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, concatenation

So I've been writing a batch file which backs up a certain file while cleaning old entries every so often. I've run into an issue where it would be simpler and more readable to store month lengths (for calculation purpose) (days1,days2,days3,etc.), and reference these by concatenating the word days with a variable which stores the month (1, 2, 3, etc.). Unfortunately, this never seems to reference the right variable correctly. Here's the relevant code, from a section calculating a date 28 days previously:

```
set days1=31
set days2=28
set days3=31
set days4=30
set days5=31
(etc.)
...
set pastmonthday=%curday%-28
set pastmonthmonth=%curmonth%
set pastmonthyear=%curyear%

if %pastmonthday% lss 0 (
    set /a pastmonthmonth=%pastmonthmonth%-1
    set /a pastmonthprevmon=1
)
if %pastmonthmonth%==0 (
    set /a pastmonthyear-=1
    set /a pastmonthmonth=12
)

set monthlengthvar=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set tempmonthlengthvar=0
if %pastmonthday% lss 0 (set tempmonthlengthvar = !days%pastmonthmonth%!)
echo.%tempmonthlengthvar%
pause
for /F "delims=" %%A in (!tempmonthlengthvar!) DO (
  endlocal
  set "monthlengthvar=%%A"
)
set pastmonthday+=%monthlengthvar%
echo.%pastmonthday%
pause
...
```

The two echoes output 0 and -7, respectively. I can't figure out why this is, no matter how I've reworked it.

Comment: Your code is way to complicated for anyone to bother working thru. Create a simpler version. Also, explain what you were hoping would result in addition to what you actually got.

Answer (score 0):

some errors (forgotten `/a` in `set`, quotes etc.)

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET /a days1=31
set /a days2=28
set /a days3=31
set /a days4=30
set /a days5=31

set /a pastmonthday=22-28
set /a pastmonthmonth=2
set /a pastmonthyear=2014

if %pastmonthday% lss 0 (
    set /a pastmonthmonth-=1
    set /a pastmonthprevmon=1
)
if %pastmonthmonth% equ 0 (
    set /a pastmonthyear-=1
    set /a pastmonthmonth=12
)

set /a monthlengthvar=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a tempmonthlengthvar=0
if %pastmonthday% lss 0 SET /a tempmonthlengthvar=!days%pastmonthmonth%!
ECHO(%tempmonthlengthvar%

for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%tempmonthlengthvar%") DO (
  IF "!"=="" endlocal
  set /a monthlengthvar=%%A
)
set /a pastmonthday+=monthlengthvar
ECHO(%pastmonthday%
```

Comment: Thanks, upon editing my code accordingly it runs as intended!